# DocuSign - getting void envelope reason

Tags: api, void, docusignapi, envelope

How can I get the reason an envelope was voided thru the API? The envelope could be voided in multiple ways so it would be nice to know if it was voided because it expired as opposed to if the sender voided it. Can this be added to the envelope status object?

Comment: Do you have sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get status of an envelope through REST, `voidedReason` is one of the responses.

[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/account/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/account/%7BaccountId%7D/envelopes/%7BenvelopeId%7D)

```
status:"voided",
..
voidedDateTime:"2014-02-02T11:37:18.5500000Z",
voidedReason:"Envelope has expired."
```

When an envelope has expired, it will show: "Envelope has expired."

When someone declines or cancels an envelope, it will show the comments they entered in the text box upon voiding.

These responses given above do not show unless the envelope is in a voided status, so you'll want your request to only use this information is status is equal to 'voided'

Comment: I am using soap and I see the voidReason property in the envelope status but it always returns nothing. Any idea why?