# Docusign add voidedReason to callback XML?

Tags: api, callback, docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign REST Api and in the create envelope request I am requesting event notifications for "voided" see below.   The callback occurs, but the voidedReason is not present in the XML, so to fetch voidedReason I have to make a separate API call to get the status of the envelope as suggested in: [DocuSign - getting void envelope reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968075/docusign-getting-void-envelope-reason).

Is there some reason (no pun intended) that voidedReason is not included in the webhook callback XML for docusignenvelopeinformation.envelopestatus?   It seems inconsistent in tha declinereason is provided in the receipientstatuses.recipientstatus object.  Would be nice to not have to make the additional API call.

```
  eventNotification: {
      url: docusignCallbackUrl,
      loggingEnabled: "true",
      includeDocumentFields: "true",
      requireAcknowledgment: "true", 
      envelopeEvents: [
        {envelopeEventStatusCode: "completed"},
        {envelopeEventStatusCode: "declined"},
        {envelopeEventStatusCode: "voided"},
      ],
      recipientEvents: [
        {recipientEventStatusCode: "Completed"},
      ],
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The DocuSign connect configuration offers a way to "Include Envelope Voided Reason" in the DocuSign connect XML payload/notification. This was added In October 2016 timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
includeEnvelopeVoidReason: "true"
```

to your *eventNotification*.

Comment: where do you add this includeEnvelopeVoidReason?